# Arduino uno r3 and wt901c ttl sensor to make compass and inclinometer

Tags: arduino-uno

Currently I'm only able to read the raw data values from the wt901c ttl sensor.

How to convert the raw data to make a tilt compensated compass and inclinometer?

Comment: I'd suggest you concentrate on a single one of it's outputs and learn to convert that into something you consider "useable" - probably a conversion from the binary output into more familiar physical units. Each output will be one of a duple or a triple, so once you have converted one axis of one of the physical, you can easily convert the other 2. Then move on to another of the device's physical measurements and do the same; learn to convert one axis, then apply what you learned to the other axes.

Comment: 1. I looked and did not find a opensource project for an Arduino and wt901c. That leaves reading the wt901c specifications and coding up a solution for your self. 2. Every magnetometer I have seen requires calibration. Depending on what you need it can be short and inaccurate or math / physically-intensive and accurate. 3. Using a gyroscope meas you accept dead reckoning errors and know how to deal w/them. 4. Most accelerometers can be used w/little calibration. 5. The accurate relation between orthogonal sensors is more important then calibrating them to match a particular unit of measure.

Comment: I took the liberty and added a real question to your post ... if you disagree with the change, then please edit your post ... your original question, `do anyone know?`, was a useless yes/no question